# MDSpreadView Customization

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there any one who has ever used MDSpreadView library on iOS? If so, how can I customize and change cells into editable cells?
The library is here: https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way for that in MDSpreadView.
The only way is to implement it yourself via custom cell by inheriting from `MDSpreadViewCell`.

Alternatively, you could try [another control](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dynamic-table-cell-classes) (though, I haven't used it personally).